Copy and paste format in a spreadsheet using gspread
Want to copy format in particular cells in google sheet and paste it in a different cell. Using batch_update to do this but getting the following error:
ERROR -
values["range"] = absolute_range_name(self.title, values["range"])
~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
gc, authorized_user = gspread.oauth_from_dict(credentials, authorized_user)
sh = gc.open('temp_sheet')

worksheet = sh.worksheet('Sheet1')

paste_type = "PASTE_FORMAT"
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "copyPaste": {
                "source": {
                    "sheetId": worksheet.id,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 30,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0, 
                    "endColumnIndex": 1,
                },
                "destination": {
                    "sheetId": worksheet.id,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,  # Row index in destination sheet
                    "endRowIndex": 30,  # Row index (exclusive)
                    "startColumnIndex": 2,  # Column index in destination sheet
                    "endColumnIndex": 3,  # Column index (exclusive)
                },
                "pasteType": paste_type,
            }
        }
    ],
}

worksheet.batch_update(body)

Output-
values["range"] = absolute_range_name(self.title, values["range"])
~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

When I saw your showing request body, I thought that it was required to use the method batch_update of classgspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet. Ref But, in your script, I guessed that you use the method batch_update of classgspread.worksheet.Worksheet. Ref I guessed that this is the reason for your current issue Output- values["range"] = absolute_range_name(self.title, values["range"]) ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'. In order to resolve this issue, please modify it as follows, and test it again.
From:
worksheet.batch_update(body)

To:
sh.batch_update(body)

